# Finding the motion of a perpendicular point

Tags: vectors

(I am re-asking this from the Physics StackExchange site where I have recieved no answers.)

Suppose I have a rigid T-shaped object, that is described by three points $A,B$ and $C$. $A$ and $B$ describe the corners of the "top" of the "T", lets say these have $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of $r_A = (0,0,1)$ and $r_B = (0,0,-1)$. The third point, point $C$ describes the bottom of the "T" and has coordinates $r_C = (1,0,0)$.

If I have two arrays which each hold the smoothly changing coordinates of points $A$ and $B$ over time, is it possible to find the coordinates of $C$? That is, given initial conditions for $A$, $B$ and $C$, $r_{A,B,C}(t_0)$ and then coordinates of $A$ and $B$ at a later time, $r_{A,B}(t)$ how can one find the coordinates of $C$, $r_{C}(t)$?

I realise that for a vector in 3D there are an infinite number of perpendicular vectors. But given the initial conditions there must be a unique solution at each timestep?

Thanks

Comment: How would you move the object to get $r_C$ to be at $(-1,0,0)$ and leave $A$ and $B$ in their original positions?